# Ошибка 'async_generator' object is not iterable

Tags: python, async-await, асинхронность, asyncio

У меня при выполнении кода выходит такая ошибка `'async_generator' object is not iterable`, как я понял все из-за функции перебора данных, но в чем именно причина я разобраться не могу, прошу помогите мне

Код:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import config
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from read_sql_config import read_db_config
import aiomysql

db_config = read_db_config()

class AsyncIterator:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.iter = iter(seq)

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        try:
            return next(self.iter)
        except StopIteration:
            raise StopAsyncIteration

# Перебор полученных данных с БД
async def iter_row():
    # инициализируем соединение с БД
    conn = await aiomysql.connect(**db_config)
    cursor = await conn.cursor()
    await cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    while True:
        rows = await cursor.fetchmany(300)
        if not rows:
            break
        async for row in AsyncIterator(rows):
            yield row

async def make_request(session, user_id, telegram_id):
    print(f"Id пользователя: {user_id} отправка: {telegram_id}")
    async with session.get(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{config.api_token}/sendMessage?',
                            params={
                                'chat_id': telegram_id,
                                'text': ("Тестовое сообщение")
                            }) as resp:
        if resp.status == 200:
            print('Работает')
        if resp.status == 400:
            print('Ошибка')
        

async def main():
    rows = iter_row()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await asyncio.gather(
            *[make_request(session, row[0], row[1]) for row in rows]
        )

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

iter_row - это async_generator по нему можно пройтись через `async for`

```py
async def main():
    rows = iter_row()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await asyncio.gather(
            *[make_request(session, row[0], row[1]) async for row in rows]
        )
```

Comment: asyncio.wait тут удобнее чем gather